# How can i include navigation for a listview in flutter ,

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z94ee.jpg)

I want each list item to have its own route .I have attached a screenshot. My list view is customized, each item has its own name

Comment: Can you provide part of your code that implement the list view?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't explain much, but rather than listview use listview.builder and then you can return any widget and pass your route based on itemindex.

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10, *//Number of items in your static or dynamic*
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return YourNewCommonWidgetForEveryItem(index);
      },
    ),
```

For example I've to navigate the first item to somewhere else

```
Widget YourNewCommonWidgetForEveryItem(int Index){
     return GestureDetector(
         onTap:()=> index==0 ? locationtofirstItem : defaullt,
         child: yourDesign(),
     ),
}
```

OfCourse the Above method won't work if you don't know where to navigate which item.

Answer (score 0):

body: new ListView(

```
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

      children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {

      return Center(

      child: ChoiceCard(

          choice: choices[index],

          item: choices[index],

             onTap: () {

                Navigator.push(

                context,

                MaterialPageRoute(

                builder: (context) => Detail(choice: choices[index])),

             );},),);}))
```